# Why is very time consuming to transform a pandas-series with pandas-datetime values into a list?

Tags: python, pandas, string-to-datetime

I had a pandas data frame in which one column contained dates given as strings (for exampel `"2014-10-17"`. I wanted to have this values as Python date objects. I decided to make this transformation in two steps:

```
df.col = pandas.to_datetime(df.col)
df.col = df.map(lambda x : x.date())
```

Before the first step, after the first step and after the second step I used the same operation to check the content of the column:

```
df.col.tolist()[:5]
```

I have noticed that when the dates were given as `strings` or `datetime.date` the above operation operation was relative fast. In contrast, when the dates were given as `pandas.datetime` objects, the operation was considerably slower.

Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to convert the entire column/series to a list and then just display the first 5 rows? Why not just show `df.col.head(5)` or `list(df.col.head(5)` if you insist on having a list?

Comment: @EdChum, in this particular case I do not have a real reason to convert to lists. But in general, it might happen that I want to have a list from a series and if `pandas.datetime` series require significantly more time for this operation, it would be nice to know that to avoid performance problems.